# Can you use springs & struts to adjust TableViewCell size for different devices?

Tags: ios, autolayout

I'm building a simple interface that contains a TableView (XCode 8, iOS 10). Most of the interface was simple to design with springs and struts. However, I don't see a way to set the springs for the TableViewCell, or it's ContentView. Consequently, when I size the device to larger sizes like an iPad, the rows stay the same height, at 44 points.

I'm not dealing with any dynamic content here, and it's fine for all the rows to be the same height. I'm just looking for a quick and easy way to have the row height adjust for the different devices so they look more proportional.

The TableCell contains a couple labels that have a larger font size specified for larger devices (wR hR) if that matters. The labels are set to spring in both vertical and horizontal directions, but are currently only changing horizontally.

Is there a way to do this using springs and struts, or do I need to switch it over to auto layout?

Thanks.

Comment: I think it's either UITableViewAutomaticDimension for cell height and autolayout or, since you're ok with the same size for each cell, you can use 'heightForRowAt' function with something like 'return self.view.frame.size.height / 6'

Comment: @jovanjovanovic No, do not use `heightForRowAt` if all rows are the same height. Instead, set the `rowHeight` property of the table view just once (probably in `viewDidLoad`).

Comment: @rmaddy what about rotation?

Comment: @jovanjovanovic Fair point. Then set `rowHeight` in the `viewWillTransition` method.

Comment: @jovanjovanovic, that works great. If you post an answer, I'll accept it. In my case, I'm only working with portrait, so I'll believe I'll follow rmaddy's suggestion to put it in viewDidLoad. In the meantime, I appreciate the help from both of you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should either use `UITableViewAutomaticDimension` for cell height and autolayout or, since you're ok with the same size for each cell, you can use `heightForRowAt` function and return something like `return self.view.frame.size.height / 6`

Comment: It's far more efficient to set the table view's `rowHeight` property than it is to implement the `heightForRowAt` delegate when all of the rows have the same height.